# How do I use SteamVR_LoadLevel to fade between scenes in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I've got this at the top,

```
    public GameObject mainCamera
```

and then I've got this within an if statement,

```
    SteamVR_LoadLevel tempload = mainCamera.GetComponent<SteamVR_LoadLevel>();
    tempload.fadeOutTime = 1f;
    tempload.fadeInTime = 1f;
    tempload.Trigger();
```

but I'm getting this error when triggering the if statement,

**Coroutine 'LoadLevel' couldn't be started because the the game object 'Camera (head)' is inactive!**

Edit 1. I figured it out, I should have made the mainCamera variable of type SteamVR_Camera and I should have nullchecked it as well as tested for it being active and enabled.

Comment: you camera is inactive. please make it first active and tell us the error

Comment: I figured it out and added an edit to the post

Answer (score 1):

Check state game object "Camera (head)" in hierarchy window and active him